# Objects are not valid as a React child - Text Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's the code that I think is giving me trouble:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      key: uuid(),
      title: "",
      author: "",
      questions: [],
      answers: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.addQuestion = this.addQuestion.bind(this);
    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // componentDidMount() is a React lifecycle method
    this.addQuestion();
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  removeItem (index) {
    this.setState(({ questions }) => {
      const mQuestions = [ ...questions ]
      mQuestions.splice(index, 1)
      return { questions: mQuestions }
    })
  }

  addQuestion() {
    questionNum++;
    this.setState(previousState => {
      const questions = [
                          ...previousState.questions,
                          <input 
                            type="text"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            name="question"
                            key={uuid()}
                          />, 
                          "hi"
                        ];
      const answers = [
                        ...previousState.answers,
                        <input 
                          type="text"
                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                          name="answer"
                        />, 
                      ];

      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        answers.push({
          answerChoice: "",
          key: uuid()
        });
      }
      return { questions, answers };
    });
    console.log(
      this.state.answers,
      this.state.questions,
      questionNum,
      this.state.title,
      this.state.author
    );
  }
//yada yada
<div className="questions">
              Now let's add some questions... <br />
              {// This is where we loop through our questions to
              // add them to the DOM.
              this.state.questions.map(question => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    {question}
                    {
                      this.state.answers.map(answer => {
                        return (
                          <div>
                            {answer}

                          </div>

                        );
                      })  
                    }
                  </div>
```

I am having trouble getting my `answerChoice~ inputs or`answers`inputs to show up in the DOM. The arrays are there when i do`console/log()` but not the actual inputs in the DOM. I am very new to React and Javacript so i don't really know what I am doing. I am getting this error right now:

```
AnswerChoice, key}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at App.js:136)
    in div (at App.js:131)
    in div (at App.js:125)
    in form (at App.js:105)
    in div (at App.js:104)
    in div (at App.js:93)
    in App (at index.js:7)
```

I don't really have much more to day. If you have questions just let me know (doing this because I apparently need more words)Any help is appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Could you include your entire render method?

Comment: can you post the entier component please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `addQuestion` function (which you call in `componentDidMount`), you are pushing an object to `answers`, but your render method expects it to be a component. Change `answers.push` to push a component instead of an object.

Like this, perhaps:

```
answers.push(<input 
                 type="text"
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                 name={uuid()}
             />);
```

Notice here that I renamed your input to the  `uuid`. This may not be desirable, but needs to be unique.

Comment: Ok, I'll give this a try. And, just curious, why do names have to be unique? Are they used a certain way?

Comment: Because in your `setState` function you use `[name]` as a key for the value in your  state. If this isn't unique, then you will overwrite your state.

Comment: Ohhhh make sa lot more sense. Btw this worked, thanks!